# Pass text from a form textbox to body of Outlook mail

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I want to draft an Outlook email from my Access form and display it so I can edit and send from Outlook.

The code below works:

```
Private Sub Command210_Click()
Dim OlApp As Object
Dim olMailItem As Object
    
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMailItem = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With olMailItem
      .Subject = Me.CPN & " " & Me.WBPN
      .Body = "this is a test"
      .Display
   End With

End Sub
```

I get a run time error when I try to use text from a form textbox (named WBEmailFU) for the body of the email.

```
Private Sub Command210_Click()
Dim OlApp As Object
Dim olMailItem As Object
    
    Set OlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMailItem = OlApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With olMailItem
      .Subject = Me.CPN & " " & Me.WBPN
      .Body = Me.WBEmailFU
      .Display
   End With

End Sub
```

I get a

> run time error  "Method 'Body' of object'_MailtItem' failed

The text box WBEmailFU is formatted as LongText.

Why does it work when I define `.body= "a text string"` but not when `.body` is defined as a text field from my form?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting `Me.WBEmailFU` to a string? (ex. `CStr(Me.WBEmailFU)`)

Comment: `WBEmailFU` is that the name of the text box?

Comment: I am not familiar with the CStr function. I will research it.

Comment: WBEmailFY is the name of the text box that contains the body of the email I want to send.

Comment: I think I figured out how to fix this. Simply add .value  See below: 
      .Body = Me.WBEmailFU.value
      
End Sub